# Admin Ajax always return 0 on form submit

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to make an ajax call on a form submit in WP.
Call seems to be good, but response is always 0 ...

I read that it meant that my call function was not found. But I believe my call is right.

I declare my ajax object :

```
function sparcraft_scripts() {
    $ajax = array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));
    wp_register_script('sparcraft-js-configurator-greement', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/sparcraft-configurator-greement.js');
    wp_localize_script('sparcraft-js-configurator-greement', 'ajax_object', $ajax);
    wp_enqueue_script('sparcraft-js-configurator-greement');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sparcraft_scripts');
```

This is my JS script :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sparcraft-configurator-form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'sparcraft_configurator_form',
                    id: 1,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log('Error : ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And my PHP script :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_sparcraft_configurator_form', 'sparcraft_configurator_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sparcraft_configurator_form', 'sparcraft_configurator_form');

function sparcraft_configurator_form() {
    $data = array("response" => "yes");
    echo json_encode($data, true);

    wp_die();
}
```

I don't understand why 0 is the only response for that call. What did I do wrong ?

Thanks for the help !

PS: I've already ask this question last week, but the account I posted it on is "unregistered" and I can't log in to it ... Sorry about that.

PS2: I've tried to replace `wp_die();` with `die();` as suggested in the other question, but response is always 0.

Comment: Are `sparcraft_configurator_form()` in the same file as `sparcraft_scripts()`? If not, where is it?

Comment: Hi @JacobPeattie et thanks for the answer. `sparcraft_scripts()` is in my functions.php file. And `sparcraft_configurator_form()` in an other php file wich is include with a `require_once`. I've already tried to set this function in the functions.php file. But no effect...

Comment: Can you try removing the second argument from `json_encode()`. That's not supposed to be a boolean and I'm not sure what the effect of using one would be.

Comment: First try echo 123, if in the console.log you get 123 you know your function runs. After you confirm that this is the right function and you get the expected result you can try removing the TRUE from the json_encode

Comment: `echo "123";` works ! And indeed, the `true` parameter fails. 
Can't remember why I wrote this one. 
Thanks for helping !